# Execlp is not working

Tags: c, linux, shell

The user must type the command and the program should execute it.
I am using fork() and execlp() but is not working. I am printing comando and ruta to see if they are good. I dont know how to make it different in order to make it work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
char comando[10];
char ruta[40];
printf("Type a command: ");
fgets(comando,10,stdin);

pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

if (pid < 0){
    perror("Error");
    return -1;
}
else if (pid == 0){ 
strcpy (ruta,"/bin/");
strcat (ruta,comando);
printf("%s",ruta);
printf("%s",comando);
execlp(ruta, comando,NULL);   
}
else{
    wait(NULL); }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Commands can have names that are 9 characters or longer; using `char comando[10];` is rather restrictive.  If you used `if (fgets(comando, sizeof(comando), stdin) == 0) { …report error and exit?… }`, then the use of `sizeof()` means you can change the variable declaration without changing other code.  Using the `if` tests prevent you using uninitialized data.  You should consider checking whether a newline was read, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execlp` is not executung command because of `fgets()`, in above `fgets()` copies `new line` at the end of `comando`. see the manual page of `fgets()`

Remove the new line as

```
fgets(comando,sizeof(comando),stdin); 
comando[strlen(comando)-1] ='\0'; /* replacing '\n' with '\0' */
```

OR  you can use `strcspn()` below as suggested by  @Jonathan Leffler.

```
comando[strcspn(comando, "\n"))] = '\0';
```

Complete working code

```
int main(){
        char comando[10];
        char ruta[40];
        printf("Type a command: ");
        fgets(comando,sizeof(comando),stdin); 
        comando[strlen(comando)-1] ='\0';
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0){
                perror("Error");
                return -1;
        }
        else if (pid == 0){ 
                strcpy (ruta,"/bin/");
                strcat (ruta,comando);  
                execlp(ruta, comando,NULL);
        }
        else{
                wait(NULL); 
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It can be better to use `comando[strcspn(comando, "\n"))] = '\0';` because it doesn't chop the last character unless it is a newline, whereas `strlen()` assumes the last character is a newline. It also doesn't break on empty strings (`strlen("") - 1` is a *large* number!).  You can also use `"\r\n"` to identify DOS/Windows or old-style Mac line endings as well as Unix line endings.  Whether that's important depends on lots of other factors — it is a nicety that probably isn't needed in this program.

Comment: yup @JonathanLeffler its surely better.

Answer (score 1):

Not all executables are in `/bin`. The point of `execlp` and [the other `exec` functions with `p` in the name](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) is that they look for the requested program in `$PATH` for you.

To help debug this kind of thing in the future, or if this doesn’t work, you should check `errno` after *every* system call (which is what `perror` does after you `fork`). When `exec*()`-family functions work, they don’t return; when they fail, they set `errno` appropriately before returning.

Comment: You're right: adding the `/bin/` prefix defeats the purpose of using `execlp()` — the code might as well use `execl()` if the prefix is added.  It is better simply to avoid adding the prefix, as you say.  (When `exec*()` functions succeed, they don't return — period.  The program has been replaced by another.  If the function returns, it failed; you don't need to test for whether it failed, but you should report an error and (usually) exit.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That’s what I meant about checking `errno`. It’s not going to be `SUCCESS`, but it will probably have useful information.